# EV3 isn't showing up in programming software after pairing on Windows XP

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

Running Windows XP x32.

I've connected, paired, connected, paired, paired, and connected, but I just can't get the EV3 software to recognize my EV3!

I've used this EV3 before on a different PC over bluetooth (and it worked), my drivers aren't screwed up, etc.

When I go to the software and try to connect to it, it doesn't show. I've refreshed about 50 times.

My EV3 Brick is running firmware `V1.09H` and is a model from Chrismas 2015, shown as Hardware version `V0.60` in the settings panel.

Comment: Was the "different computer" also Windows XP. Windows XP has not been supported for years, so I doubt that LEGO tests that the EV3 software works on XP.

Comment: No. It was Vista (but I don't think Vista is really much better than XP...)

Comment: One thing I would try is:  Press Win+R, type `bthprops.cpl`, hit enter, go to the hardware tab, and make sure that your bluetooth adapter is listed.  In my case dispite the adapter being in Device Manager it was not listed here, meaning Windows didn't know it was a bluetooth adapter.  I think the software that came with my adapter on the CD took control of the adapter away from Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software uses Bluetooth functions that were [introduced in Windows Vista SP2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-support-in-previous-windows-versions#span-idwhatprogramminginterfaceswereintroducedinwindowsvistaspanspan-idwhatprogramminginterfaceswereintroducedinwindowsvistaspanspan-idwhatprogramminginterfaceswereintroducedinwindowsvistaspanwhat-programming-interfaces-were-introduced-in-windows-vista). Quoting the linked article, "Windows Vista with SP2 and Windows 7 also support the user-mode RFComm and Bluetooth APIs." (The EV3 uses RFCOMM to communicate via Bluetooth.)

So, EV3 Bluetooth will not work on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: https://lc-www-live-s.legocdn.com/r/www/r/mindstorms/-/media/franchises/mindstorms%202014/support/bluetooth%20support%20for%20ev3.pdf?l.r2=-716871911 (and my memory) seem to indicate otherwise.  I think the article from MS was saying that SCO, SDP, and L2CAP were first introduced in Vista and that "Windows Vista with SP2 and Windows 7 also support the user-mode RFComm and Bluetooth APIs", but not that RFComm was only in Vista+.

Comment: I just got my EV3 working over Bluetooth again on my XP laptop, so it is indeed possible.

Comment: Cool. Perhaps you should turn your comments into an answer explaining how you got it working.

Comment: Answer posted.                             .

Answer (score 1):

The key is to make sure the driver works with MS's bluetooth stack, and doesn't just use it's own stack.

Press Win+R, type `bthprops.cpl` (or maybe `irprops.cpl`, it's been a while), hit enter.  Check the `Hardware` tab to make sure your device actually shows up.  If not, try different drivers/manually installing the driver using the "Have disk" method.  3rd party bluetooth stacks may disable the MS one seeing the device, even if the device/driver supports the MS stack.